# Three js clock is not defined

Tags: three.js

So I wanted to use three js and ammo.js but I have encountered an error in which it says clock is not defined.

Here is part of the index.js:

```
//import
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'

//Call clock
clock = new THREE.Clock();
```

Index.html

```
<script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "three": "./build/three.module.js",
          "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls": "./jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js",
          "three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module": "./jsm/libs/stats.module.js",
          "three/examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module": "./jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Server.js

```
const { randomInt } = require('crypto');
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = 8080;

const path = require("path")

app.use(express.static("./public"))
app.use('/build/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/build')));
app.use('/jsm/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/examples/jsm')));

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${port}`)
})
```

If anybody knows how to solve this, well thank you

Comment: Maybe define the clock? ``let clock= ...``

Comment: Yeah you are right, dunno how I missed such a stupid thing. Thank you